# error: Illegal zero sized array

Tags: c++, templates

I get this error:

```
error C2229: class 'GenerateRandNum<int [],int>' has an illegal zero-sized array
```

In my main, I call my random generator function to input into a empty data set

I call the method in my main like so:

```
//declare small array
const  int smallSize = 20;
int smallArray[smallSize];

// call helper function to put random data in small array
GenerateRandNum <int[], int> genData(smallArray, smallSize);
genData.generate();
```

Header file

```
template <class T, class B>
class GenerateRandNum
{
public:

    T data;
    B size;


    GenerateRandNum(T list, B length)
    {
        data = list;
        size = length;
    }
    void generate();

};
```

File with method definition

```
template<class T, class B>
void GenerateRandNum<T, B> ::generate()
{

    for (B i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        data[0] = 1 + rand() % size;
    }

}
```

Comment: The types of `genData` template parameters will not be deduced from the constructor arguments, you need to pass them explicitly: `GenerateRandNum<int[20], int>`.

Comment: In addition, you cannot do this `data = list` because arrays cannot be assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your approach:

- The first array template parameter can't have its dimension deduced from the argument as n.m. noted, you would need to specify it explicitly:

  ```
  GenerateRandNum<int[20], int>
  ```
- There no point in doing

  ```
  data = list
  ```

  since in your code sample these are two arrays and you can't assign them directly. You can either copy the memory or specialize your routines/template
- You should really consider using a vector of integers, e.g.

  ```
  template <class T, class B>
  class GenerateRandNum
  {
  public:
      T data;
      B size;
      GenerateRandNum(T list, B length) {
          data = list;
          size = length;
      }
      void generate();
  };

  template<class T, class B>
  void GenerateRandNum<T, B> ::generate()
  {
      srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); // You should initialize with a seed
      for (B i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          data[i] = 1 + rand() % size; // I believe you wanted data[i] and not data[0]
      }
  }

  int main(){

      //declare small array
      const  int smallSize = 20;
      std::vector<int> smallArray(smallSize);

      // call helper function to put random data in small array
      GenerateRandNum <std::vector<int>, int> genData(smallArray, smallSize);
      genData.generate();
  }
  ```

  <kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/A7Pxjd)</kbd>

I fixed two issues in the code above, take a look at the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers and arrays are not the same in C/C++. They are two very different things. However, arrays *decay* into pointers. Most notably in function declarations: The declaration

```
void foo(int array[7]);
```

is defined to be equivalent to

```
void foo(int* array);
```

That said, all the `GenerateRandNum` constructor gets, is a `int*` because that's what `T = int []` decays to in the function declaration context. The `data` member of `GenerateRandNum`, however, is of type `int []` (no decay here), which your compiler assumes to be a zero sized array. Consequently, when you try to assign a pointer to the array, your compiler complains.

You have two options to fix this:

1. You use an `std::vector<>` instead, as Marco A. suggests.
2. You declare your `GenerateRandNum` class as:

   ```
   template <class T>
   class GenerateRandNum {
       public:
           T* data;
           size_t size;

           GenerateRandNum(T* list, size_t length) {
               data = list;
               size = length;
           }
           void generate();
   };
   ```

Note:
I have removed the template parameter for the size type: `size_t` is guaranteed to be suitable for counting anything in memory, so there is absolutely no point in using anything different. Templating this parameter only obfuscates your code.